# How to remove extra whitespace between prefix and value in XML element using attributes?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, erp

I have an XML code snippet as follows:

```
<element id="billNoPre" class="LabelText" value="Reference:0-" field="">
    <matrix x="0" y="0" height="10" scaleX="1" scaleY="1" rotation="0" />
    <style fontStyle="normal" lineHeight="100%" textAlign="right" fontSize="10" fontWeight="bold" fontFamily="calibriEmbedded" />
</element>

<element id="billNo" class="LabelText" prefixElement="billNoPre" value="00.00" field="billNumber">
    <matrix x="440" y="15" height="15" scaleX="1" scaleY="1" rotation="0" />
    <style fontStyle="normal" lineHeight="100%" textAlign="right" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="10" fontFamily="calibriEmbedded" />
</element>
```

When I retrieve the value of the billNo element, it includes extra whitespace between the prefix "Reference:0-" and the actual value "4564564564". The current output is "Reference:0- 4564564564", but I want it to be "Reference:0-4564564564" without any extra whitespace.

How can I modify the code to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Where does the value come from? It's not present in the XML anywhere. Also, what code do you use to extract it?

Comment: The issue is with the output, not with the input data. Something that is taken from just your description. But if you want an explanation on how to fix this, you need to show the code you use.